# Multivariable linear gradient descent resulting in inf

Tags: python, linear-regression, gradient-descent, numpy

I am trying to implement a multivariable gradient descent algorithm, it seems to start working fine, and works on smaller datasets, but applying it to larger datasets the variables overflow and cause an inf (at least thats what I think is happening).

```
def standard_fit(self, x, y):
    # add a column of 1s
    x = np.array(np.hstack((np.ones((len(x), 1)), x)))
    dt = np.zeros(self.m)

    for i in range(self.max_iter):
        # Predict y
        pred_y = np.dot(x, self.theta)

        # Calculate loss
        loss = pred_y - y

        # Calculate gradient of the cost
        dt = np.dot(x.T, loss)

        # modify theta
        prev_theta = self.theta.copy()
        self.theta -= self.alpha * dt

        # Check precision
        if abs(sum(self.theta - prev_theta)) < self.precision:
            print("PRECISION MET!")
            break

        if i % 100 == 0:
            # Calculate cost
            pred_cost = self.cost(pred_y, y)
            print("ITERATION " + str(i) + ": " + str(pred_cost)
```

- **m** is the number of features (+1 to consider the row of ones).
- **precision** is how small a step it should take before stopping
- **theta** is my feature weights

I've been stuck on this problem for more time than I'd be willing to admit. Watching videos on it I see people dividing the gradient by dividing it by the number of features after the calculation, this does nothing.

I also saw someone sum the gradient, which really makes no sense to me as surely then it would modify all the thetas evenly?

Comment: The code seems to be ok. The solution is to scale your data frame prior applying gradient descent with StandarScaler

Comment: writing my own standardscaler function that took data, subtracted the mean and then dividing by the std did not work

Comment: glad to hear it worked! regards

Comment: It did not work

Comment: It is great!!!!

Comment: The too-large learning rate can ruin the calculation -- you overshoot the critical point. Did you try decreasing it? If you don't want to manually tune it, use, for example, the Armijo rule: http://web.mit.edu/6.252/www/LectureNotes/6_252%20Lecture04.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me.